# How to do something at the end of a Youtube video

Tags: android, video, youtube

I'm currently launching a Youtube video using this piece of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://"+token));
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, SmartBrowserWebViewActivity.ACT_YOUTUBE);
```

It works great. But I would like at the end of the video play to get the capability to do what I want. For example how to change activity when the video is over ?

Currently the user has to click back and I can handle it through the onActivityResult, but is there a way to avoid the user click on "back"?

Maybe I should play flash video to do it or HTML5 video ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Implement and OnCompletionListener. Here is an example of my code. It should work the same as a RAW file video.

```
 final VideoView vs = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.imlsplash);
// Set video link (mp4 format )
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName() +"/" +R.raw.iphonesplashfinal);
vs.setVideoURI(video);
vs.requestFocus();
vs.start();
vs.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {                

        startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
                CurrentActivity.this.finish();      
}
});
}
```

you may have to replace the videoView with whatever you are using.
If you are using a URL change URI to URL and add URL in place of    `"android.resource://"+getPackageName() +"/" +R.raw.iphonesplashfinal`

Comment: Your solution involves implementing a VideoView and playing the video natively, whereas the question is asking if anything can be done after the video completes in the browser (since its being fired off as an intent). What you wrote looks like it would work, but its actually a different way of playing the video and not really within the realm of the question.

Comment: Ok, but is the concept not similar? I agree with what are saying though.

Comment: yes. concept is similar and I think the author will not be able to accomplish what its trying to do without using a videoview and native video. Although, you could try to play the video in a WebView and hook into the JavaScript API for youtube....just a thought.